# Indexed copy of two buffers

Tags: opencl, gpu, gpgpu

I have the following routine that is supposed to copy elements from src matrix to the dst matrix based on the indexes found in index. The index is computed correctly but the dst is not updated. What am I missing?

```
__kernel void
src_indexed_copy(__global real *dst, __global const real *src,
   __global const int *index, int src_offset)
{
        int id = get_global_id(ROW_DIM);
        int src_idx = src_offset + index[id];
        dst[id] = src[src_idx];
}
```

The global workspace has as many work items as there are indices in the index array.

The linear code would look something like this:

```
for (k = 0; k < n; k++) {
        dst[k] = src[m * column + index[k]];
}
```

Which copies all the indexed elements from column column in matrix src.

This is how I am reading the buffer back (asked in comments):

```
rc = clEnqueueReadBuffer(ompctx->clctx.queue, c,
        CL_TRUE, 0, i * sizeof(real), &tmp[0],
        0, NULL, NULL);
if (rc != CL_SUCCESS) {
    log_error("omp", "[%d] readbuf() failed", rc);
    goto err;
}
log_info("omp", "c");
for (k = 0; k < i; k++) {
    log_info("omp", "%6.8f", tmp[k]);
}
```

Comment: How do you know the index is computed correctly? Try dst[id] = id to verify your host code.

Comment: I printf'ed it and I also did dst[id] = 515 and dst[id] = id. And dst still looks the same. And while printf'ing I saw that the index is calculated correctly.

Comment: Then you may not read dst back correctly. How are you doing it?

Comment: Added above. I always get zeroes no matter what.

Comment: @PaulIrofti: It would really help if you could give us a simple, non working but compilable extract of your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something must be wrong in the host code.  Please verify:

- the return value of **all** OpenCL API calls,
- the buffer creation flags (you need WRITE access to the destination buffer),
- kernel arguments correspond to the kernel code.